# Loading Animation Only Showing After Button Function (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, save, loading

I am attempting to show a loading animation while generating and saving a new array to NSUserDefaults. The animation functions are called in the function shown below:

```
    func getOrCreateCalendar(forYear: Int) -> [DetailedDate] {
       if forYear == date.getDateComponents(todaysDetailDate.date).year && calendar.count > 0 {
           print("forYear == today's year and the current calendar has been RETURNED FROM MEMORY")

           return calendar
       } else {
           let existingCalendar = getExistingCalendar(forYear)

           if existingCalendar != nil {
               return existingCalendar!
           } else {
               SwiftSpinner.show("Generating new calendar for \(forYear)", animated: true)

               let calendar = generateCalendarFor(forYear)

               print("GENERATED NEW calendar for \(forYear)")

               SwiftSpinner.show("Saving calendar", animated: false)

               saveNew(calendar, year: forYear)

               SwiftSpinner.hide()

               return calendar
           }
       }
```

I am using the open source SwiftSpinner animation as shown above.
I call this function in multiple places throughout my code (especially buttons throughout the app).

However, whenever this function is called the animation does not show until the entire process has completed. 
Why is this? How can I show the animation while generating and saving new content and then dismiss it upon completion?

Comment: Have you tried to create and save your calendar in a background thread?
The whole UI is processed in the main-thread; if you block the main-thread, the UI gets stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to perform the action in a background-queue using the following code:

```
SwiftSpinner.show("Generating new calendar for \(forYear)", animated: true)
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), {
    let calendar = generateCalendarFor(forYear)

    print("GENERATED NEW calendar for \(forYear)")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        SwiftSpinner.show("Saving calendar", animated: false)
    })

    saveNew(calendar, year: forYear)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        SwiftSpinner.hide()
        onCompletion(calendar)
    })
})
```

What you do here:

- you create a background-queue
- create the calendar
- update the UI from the main-queue (`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { SwiftSpinner.show("Saving calendar", animated: false) })` (main-queue is important because the UI shpuld only be modified from the main-queue)
- save the calendar (in the background-queue again)
- call a custom function (here I named it `onCompletion` in the main-queue which does something with the calendar (replaces `return calendar`)

You should make sure that your UI-buttons etc. are disabled before `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), { ... })` gets called and enabled again in `onCompletion` else the user would be able to press some buttons while your app is working (and maybe change some data used by the queue -> not good).

**Why:**
The UI is updated from the main-queue, but usually not immediately after you call the code to update it; if you block the main-queue, your UI cannot be updated. So we do the work in a background-queue so your main-queue can update the UI.

**In detail:**
You call `dispatch_async` (from GrandCentralDispatch) which creates a new queue with the priority `QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED` (~normal priority). Then it passes the code in the curly braces to this queue; the OS will execute the queue in a separate thread.
Because the UI must only be modified from the main-queue, we pass the code that updates the UI (`SwiftSpinner.show("Saving calendar", animated: false)`) to the main-queue by using `dispatch_async` again.

The use of a completion-function is necessary because the code/queue is executed in the background and independently from `getOrCreateCalendar`; your function probably returns before the queue is completed and the calendar created and saved.

Comment: Thank you for the well explained and detailed answer, @k-biermann. I think this is exactly the sort of thing I need to be doing. I am new to asynchronous code and I appreciate the assistance. I do still have an issue though. I return this array (aka calendar) in numerous places to replace my main calendar as well as a few additional calendars. How can I use a completion function to replace the returns at every block of this function? Do I need to refactor my code at every place I call this function as well?

Comment: Well, it would be the easiest solution. You could also pass an empty reference as parameter or use a global var. But this is not as easy as it sounds because you have to avoid collisions and so on. So yeah, I would refactor your code and replace every return with a call to `onComplete`.

Comment: Reformatted my code. Used a completion function that I pass in as trailing closures at every call. Works perfectly.